# How to convert ArrayList into Scala Array in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I want to create a StructType dynamically out of a json file. I iterate my fields and I want to find out how (if it is even possible) can I create some list with my iteration, and then to create a StructType from it.

The code I've tried:

```java
List<StructField> structFieldList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String field : fields.values()) {
  StructField sf = Datatypes.createStructField(field, DataTypes.StringType, true);
  structFieldList.add(sf);
}
StructType structType = new StructType(structFieldList.toArray());
```

But this one is pretty impossible. Is there any way to figure this out?

Comment: Why can't you just add fields to struct one by one, using `StructType.add(StructField)`? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html#add-org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField- Or maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you don't need to convert `ArrayList` to Scala `Array`, as `StructType` constructor takes java `StructField[]` array as argument.

Your code can be changed by setting type when calling `.toArray()` method in your last line of code snippet so it returns a `StructField[]` array instead of an `Object[]` array:

```java
List<StructField> structFieldList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String field : fields.values()) {
  StructField sf = DataTypes.createStructField(field, DataTypes.StringType, true);
  structFieldList.add(sf);
}
StructType structType = new StructType(structFieldList.toArray(new StructField[0]));
```